# How can I load a file from a HTML input into Emscripten's MEMFS file system?

Tags: javascript, webassembly, emscripten

I have an HTML input like this `<input type="file" id="myfile" onchange="load_file()">`.
I want to load the file into Emscripten's MEMFS file system.
Looking at the [Emscripten file API](https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/Filesystem-API.html) I have been trying to use FS.mount() to do so.

However, the documentation only gives an example of using mount using WORKERFS, so I tried playing around with it like this.

```
let files = document.getElementById('myfile').files;
let file=files[0];
FS.mount(MEMFS, {files: file },'test');
console.log(FS.readFile('test/' + file.name));
```

But get a "No such file or directory" error message when I try to read the file.

Any suggestions of where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing–

input_test.html for file input:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="file" id="myfile" onchange="load_file()"> 
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="auto_em.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="input_test.js"></script>
</html>
```

input_test.js then reads the file as an ArrayBuffer and then uses a Uint8Array view of that buffer to write the file to Emscripten's MEMFS:

```
let reader= new FileReader();

function load_file(){
    let files = document.getElementById('myfile').files;
    let file=files[0];
    reader.addEventListener('loadend', print_file);
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}

function print_file(e){
    let result=reader.result;
    const uint8_view = new Uint8Array(result);

    FS.writeFile('write_test.txt', uint8_view)
    Module.ccall('print_file', 'number', ['string'], ['write_test.txt'])
}
```

print_input.cpp to print out file to check it worked:

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern "C" {

int print_file(char* file_path){

    FILE *file = fopen(file_path, "r");
    if (!file) {
        printf("cannot open file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    while (!feof(file)) {
        char c = fgetc(file);
        if (c != EOF) {
            putchar(c);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
}
```

then compiled using:

```
emcc print_input.cpp -o auto_em.js -s "EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS=['_print_file']" -s "EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=['ccall']" -s FORCE_FILESYSTEM=1
```